# beforeunload functionality with out confirmation message

Tags: jquery

I want to catch the tab close event. for that I used bellow code,

```
$(window).bind("beforeunload", function() {
        return confirm("Do you really want to close?");
})
```

- This would warn the user before leaving the page.This is fine. But I
  don't want to display conformation message to the user, just I
  capture that situation i.e I want to save that tab closing time  at
  my backend logic, for that I wrote like bellow but it didn't work,

  ```
  $(window).bind("beforeunload", function() {
          // code hear
  });
  ```

  If I remove the return statement like above, even it wont call.
  please any one help me out

Comment: what you want to perform when the window is closed?

Comment: I want to save the time when is the user closed that particular tab.

Comment: you can use onunload event but it is not supported in chrome and opera.

Answer (score 0):

you can write a webservice fot that and make an ajax call to the webservice.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",

        url: uriOfWebservice,

        success: function (msg) {

        },
        error: function (error) {

        }
    });
```

in web service write the code to enter time in backend
eg. your webservice url is: D:/abc/myservice.asmx/recordTime

Webservice method

```
[WebMethod]
public void recordTime()
{
     //Code to enter time in backend
}
```